# PL/SQL inline functions are not supported by Flyway?

Tags: oracle, plsql, flyway

Since Oracle 12c it is possible to write inline functions in an SQL query, consider [Inline Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#functions)
However, apparently it does not work when using this syntax in flyway scripts. As far as I understand the Flyway documentation, this kind of usage was not considered, consider [Flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle#sql-script-syntax): The "SQL Script Syntax" section. When I try to use it I keep getting

```
ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := ; not null default character
```

So, do I understand it right that I can't use inline PL/SQL functions with Flyway?

Here is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
WITH
FUNCTION testfunction (input IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  return 'fffff';
END;
SELECT
  testfunction(2) AS TEST_COLUMN
FROM dual;
/
```

Comment: Just add an `/` after your script.

Comment: I read about it already. That did not help. I added a test script to my post. With SQL Developer it runs, by flyway it throws the mentioned exception.

Comment: You need to have a `/` *on the next line* after every PL/SQL program block, which is basically every block that ends with `end;`. But in this case, the `/` should not be needed, since the function is inlined in the view, and the statement only ends after `from dual`. Seems like this is indeed a Flyway shortcoming. I think Flyway is trying to break up the script in separate statements, but fails on this view.

Comment: I think it is the same issue like here with liquibase [liquibase issue](http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2014/05/liquibase-and-plsql-with-oracle-db.html)

Comment: Hmmm, I thought Flyway's USP was that it handles SQL as is, wrangling ["unmodified SQL files generated by your native tools containing all kinds of complexity"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39052447/146325). Perhaps @axelfontaine will notice this question and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use an anonymous PL/SQL block to create the view?

```
--Create view with dynamic SQL to avoid Flyway parser bug.
begin
    execute immediate q'[
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
WITH
FUNCTION testfunction (input IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  return 'fffff';
END;
SELECT
  testfunction(2) AS TEST_COLUMN
FROM dual
]';
end;
/
```